# Insert Button at Footer

Tags: shopify

I would like to add this whatsapp button at the footer region (http://prntscr.com/rvlsit) at my site https://chirpygold.com/

The whatsapp button is already uploaded here: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0349/2541/2397/files/whatsapp-button.png?v=1586370150

The button should click to: https://wa.me/13158991622

Can someone provide a code to add to the footer file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add smth like this at the end of `<ul class="no-bullets site-footer__linklist ">` within `footer` section:

```html
<li>
  <a href="https://wa.me/13158991622">
    <img
         src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0349/2541/2397/files/whatsapp-button.png?v=1586370150" 
         style="
                max-width: 200px;
                "
     />
  </a>
</li>
```

It will look like:

[image]